# mongoexport - Not exporting all docs

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

I am using the below doc to do a mongoexport

```
mongoexport -d test -c test_collection --fields=_id,name --csv --out output.csv 2> error.err
```

This is the output of mongoexport after completion

```
2020-01-08T07:45:50.351-0800    [#######################.]  test.test_collection  34808000/34981217  (99.5%)
2020-01-08T07:45:51.351-0800    [#######################.]  test.test_collection  34808000/34981217  (99.5%)
2020-01-08T07:45:52.294-0800    [#######################.]  test.test_collection  34981196/34981217  (100.0%)
2020-01-08T07:45:52.294-0800    exported 34981196 records
```

It is showing 34981217 to be exported, but exports only 34981196 with a discrepancy of 21 documents. Any idea why this may be happening. Just to add I am doing a mongoexport with --readPreference '{mode:"secondaryPreferred"}'

Comment: Have you tried this without specifying a readPreference, or specifying a readPreference of "primary" or "primaryPreferred"?

Comment: Is the collection being actively used during the export? E.g. what is the possibility that the 21 documents were deleted during the export process?

Comment: mongoexport doc say that some records might be missed when running non-primary. I cannot run primary as it is on production and risky.